# Count the unique Values that met the Criterias (without using Pivot and Unique() function)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need help in counting the unique Type of the table if they showed twice on the record with Code 1 function that doesn't use Pivot or Unique() formula.

As you can see on the screenshot below, I used a pivot table to get the unique Employee number and showed its Type and Function (Column F-I). Basically a summary of the whole table.

By doing that i'll be able to get the final count of all unique Employee ID with Function Code 1 that has more than 2 entries (Column K-M). Only Employee 2 and Employee 4 (a total of 2 unique Count) should be counted as they both have 2 entries with Code 1 function.

*Note I did not count Employee 6 (highlighted in red) as it is under Code 2 even though it has 2 entries.*

Is there a way to do this without using pivot and not using latest MS office function such as Unique(). Thank you!

[image]

| Employee Number | Type | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | Alpha | Code 1 |
| Employee 2 | Alpha | Code 1 |
| Employee 3 | Alpha | Code 1 |
| Employee 4 | Alpha | Code 1 |
| Employee 2 | Alpha | Code 1 |
| Employee 4 | Alpha | Code 1 |
| Employee 9 | Beta | Code 1 |
| Employee 6 | Beta | Code 2 |
| Employee 7 | Beta | Code 1 |
| Employee 9 | Beta | Code 1 |
| Employee 5 | Beta | Code 1 |
| Employee 6 | Beta | Code 2 |
| Employee 8 | Beta | Code 1 |

Answer (score 0):

This should work for either the 2007 or 2010 version.

Populate cells E4 and down using: `=COUNTIFS(B$4:B$16,B4,C$4:C$16,C4,D$4:D$16,D4)`

Populate cells M4:M5 using: `=COUNTIFS(C$4:C$16,K4,D$4:D$16,L4,E$4:E$16,">1")/2`

Comment: Hi @Clif thank you for answering, but I am looking for a more dynamic formula. the only available data for filtering is column K4:L5. with those cells, formula should be able to provide how many count the unique Employee Number with Alpha and Code 1 that has more than 2 entries

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, then one would need `FREQUENCY()` function to accomplish the desired output.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H4</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(IF(($F4=$C$4:$C$16)*($G4=$D$4:$D$16),
 FREQUENCY(MATCH($B$4:$B$16&"|"&($F4=$C$4:$C$16)*($G4=$D$4:$D$16),
 $B$4:$B$16&"|"&($F4=$C$4:$C$16)*($G4=$D$4:$D$16),0),
 (ROW($B$4:$B$16)-ROW($B$4)+1))>1,0),0)))
```

---

- `MATCH()` function --> Concatenating with `|` the `Employee Number` Range with the `Boolean` values of matching with `Type` & `Function` cells in columns `F` & `G` with the corresponding ranges in `C` & `D` and then looking for matching values in the same concatenated array to find the duplicates.
- `FREQUENCY()` function --> This is used to count the number of occurrences of each unique values in the array returned from the `MATCH()` function using the `ROW()` numbers of the Column B(which converts to an array of relative reference numbers) so as to return the relative counts.
- `IF()` function --> Before doing the above steps, we need to determine whether the `Type` & `Function` in Column `F` & `G` matches with the ranges in `C` & `D`, if it does, we are doing the above else to return a `0`.
- `IFERROR()` function ensures to remove the error values by `0` and `N()` function converts the returned array into numbers.
- Lastly using `SUMPRODUCT()` function to calculate the sum of two arrays.

---

Screenshots showing below to relate with the steps:

[image]

---