# Is there a formula to Count Unique values with Criteria and between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need help to count all **UNIQUE** each **Serial #** of each **Phase #** between two dates.
Raw data changes every day. I know there is a way to formulate this but I can't do it.

I tried Cleaning the raw data with Remove Duplicates of "**Serial #**" and "**Phase #**" and using countif formula between range but it gives me an incorrect count vs manual counting/filtering.

[image]

| Serial # | Phase # | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TKP-45160 | 7400000 | 02-Jan-24 |
| SIF-99993 | 7400000 | 03-Jan-24 |
| MXP-78670 | 7400000 | 09-Jan-24 |
| TKP-45160 | 7400000 | 14-Jan-24 |
| IGB-61886 | 7400001 | 09-Jan-24 |
| UGZ-18592 | 7400001 | 12-Jan-24 |
| UKI-16823 | 7400001 | 16-Jan-24 |
| LEI-46548 | 7400001 | 17-Jan-24 |
| VEN-90058 | 7400002 | 04-Jan-24 |
| VEN-90058 | 7400002 | 16-Jan-24 |
| VEN-90058 | 7400002 | 22-Jan-24 |
| BQV-31917 | 7400003 | 16-Jan-24 |
| HZU-76576 | 7400003 | 19-Jan-24 |
| YCF-16393 | 7400005 | 02-Jan-24 |
| IQW-54705 | 7400005 | 11-Jan-24 |
| CJZ-61175 | 7400005 | 12-Jan-24 |
| BYS-13223 | 7400006 | 04-Jan-24 |
| SPI-15979 | 7400006 | 08-Jan-24 |
| HUU-10645 | 7400006 | 10-Jan-24 |
| BYS-13223 | 7400006 | 12-Jan-24 |
| BYS-13223 | 7400006 | 14-Jan-24 |
| REP-36224 | 7400006 | 16-Jan-24 |
| WKG-85714 | 7400007 | 04-Jan-24 |
| VIN-86315 | 7400007 | 06-Jan-24 |
| VZM-12692 | 7400007 | 07-Jan-24 |
| DKX-32255 | 7400007 | 18-Jan-24 |
| OTJ-13529 | 7400007 | 21-Jan-24 |

Comment: You tagged both Excel 2010 and 2007, which are you using? Any of these or a more recent version (Microsoft 365 or Excel 2021)

Comment: Also define unique. Do you want to exclude duplicates, or do you want to count distinct uniques?

Comment: Hi @P.b, Most of our PC is using 2016 version, I am using 365, I am not the only one who will use this template. I Tag 2010 and 2007 version for compatibility option. i know that some 365 formula/function wont work on lower versions.

Unique as in count all duplicates as 1 count

Comment: the safest is 2016 version. Thank you!

Comment: Found you had interesting questions sometime back posted a solution there as well, let me know if that works for you or not: **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76536013/8162520)** this uses `FREQUENCY()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula using `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` function along with `IF()` with `COUNTIFS()`

Using `SUM()` function one would require to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while using `SUMPRODUCT()` it won't require.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I4</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(($F4=$C$4:$C$30)*($D$4:$D$30>=$G4)*($D$4:$D$30<=$H4),
  1/COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$30,F4,$B$4:$B$30,$B$4:$B$30,$D$4:$D$30,">="&$G4,$D$4:$D$30,"<="&$H4),0))
```

---

Formula needs to fill down!

---

Another alternative using `FREQUENCY()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(IF(($F4=$C$4:$C$30)*($D$4:$D$30>=$G4)*($D$4:$D$30<=$H4),
 FREQUENCY(MATCH($B$4:$B$30&"|"&($F4=$C$4:$C$30)*($D$4:$D$30>=$G4)*($D$4:$D$30<=$H4),
 $B$4:$B$30&"|"&($F4=$C$4:$C$30)*($D$4:$D$30>=$G4)*($D$4:$D$30<=$H4),0),
 (ROW($B$4:$B$30)-ROW($B$4)+1))>0,0),0)))
```

---

The above has been explained here:

**[Count the unique Values that met the Criterias (without using Pivot and Unique() function)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869179/8162520)**

---