# Excel consecutive number counting

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I know there has been a lot of conversation on this site regarding consecutive occurrences of numbers, but none of the solutions seemed to help my work whatsoever.

The task I've been given is the following: I.ve got 3 columns of information; one is the date, one is an ID number, and one is the ID numbers sorted in a way that one particular number only appears once. Out of this information, I need to count the max consecutive occurrences of the ID numbers based on the dates.

The date column appears so that for each day there are multiple occurrences of the same ID number and there are multiple numbers in a certain day, but I don't need to work with that I assume, I only need to know how many consecutive days the certain ID number appeared.

I've already tried some formulas from other similar questions, but they all seem to work only when the date column consists of days that are consecutive and no double occurrences and all. The last and most promising formula I used is this:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(X:X=AD2;ROW(X:X));IF(X:X<>AD2;ROW(X:X);)))
```

where X is the ID number and AD is the ID number sorted. Sadly this doesnt seem to work either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

| date_of_day | ID number | unique ID |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024.01.01 | 100 | 100 | 3 |  |
| 2024.01.01 | 100 | 200 | 4 |  |
| 2024.01.01 | 100 | 300 | 2 |  |
| 2024.01.01 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.01 | 300 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.02 | 100 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.02 | 300 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.02 | 300 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.02 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 100 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 200 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 300 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 100 |  |  |  |
| 2024.01.03 | 100 |  |  |  |

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add example easy to copy/paste and expected output.

Comment: Is it *"max consecutive occurrences"* or *"consecutive days"*? You say *"how many consecutive days the certain ID number appeared"* yet your formula doesn't account for the days (dates). Please share some sample data as text, a screenshot of your sheet including the desired results (hide irrelevant columns), and an explanation of the logic used to get them.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4KruvZH       Here is a link to the sample data, I don't know if it works.

Comment: So for example in the example above there are different and identical numbers in a given day. I don't need the number of occurences for a certain ID number in a given day, but the number of consecutive occurences of that ID number one after the other based on the dates. So if the ID 100 is listen on 2024.01.02 and 2024.01.03. then my desired number would be 2. But if it’s listed on 2024.01.01. and 2024.01.03. then it’s gonna be 1, because there is a break based on the date.

Comment: What about countif() or countifs() ?

Comment: please update your question with the sample data - it is easier to help you if you add them via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation). Reading [ask] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @SolarMike I can't really use them, I have the same problem. It can count the number of occurences in a given date but I can't get it to work on consecutive dates, meawhile excluding the occurences of the numbers in a given day. So in the example above it can count that there is 3 occurences of the ID 100 in 2024.01.01 but it can't count beyond that day, I would need additional formulas for that, and I got absolutely no idea how to make that work.

Comment: What if an ID occurs twice on one day and once on the next -- should it be counted as two or three? In your example above, `300` occurs on `1.1`, `1.2` and `1.3` but is only counted as `2`. Why is that?  And why is `200` counted as `4` when it only occurs on three consecutive days?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld If an ID occurs twice on one day and once on the next, the ideal outcome would be if it was counted as 2. 200 is counted as 4 because the above mentioned formula only counts the maximum number of consecutive occurences, it doesn't take the dates into consideration, that is what I need to include somewhere but I have no idea where and how.

Answer (score 2):

The way the question reads to me is that you need to find the maximum number of consecutive days that contain a particular ID. You could do this by using Countifs with the unique dates and the current ID as criteria, then use either a lambda or frequency to find the longest run of values greater than 0 in the result e.g. using a lambda:

```
=LET(dates,A$2:A$18,
uniqueDates,UNIQUE(A$2:A$18),
IDs,B$2:B$18,
countPerDate,COUNTIFS(dates,uniqueDates,IDs,C2),
MAX(SCAN(0,countPerDate,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c>0,a+1,0)))))
```

The final result is 3 in each case because each one of the IDs occurs at least once in each day:

[image]

If ID 100 doesn't occur in (say) the second day, the result for that ID is 1:

[image]

You can make it a spill formula if you want to using Byrow:

```
=BYROW(C2:C4,
  LAMBDA(r,LET(dates,A2:A18,
  uniqueDates,UNIQUE(A2:A18),
  IDs,B2:B18,
  countPerDate,COUNTIFS(dates,uniqueDates,IDs,r),
  MAX(SCAN(0,countPerDate,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c>0,a+1,0))))))
)
```

or using Frequency:

```
=BYROW(C2:C4,
LAMBDA(r,LET(dates,A2:A18,
uniqueDates,UNIQUE(A2:A18),
IDs,B2:B18,
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uniqueDates)),
countPerDate,COUNTIFS(dates,uniqueDates,IDs,r),
MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(countPerDate>0,seq),IF(countPerDate=0,seq)))))
)
```

Comment: You may well be right but like I said that's just my reading of the question, hopefully OP can clarify.

Comment: I think if you look at the answer to @Ron Rosenfeld's comment it tends to support my theory.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya OP's 2nd comment is rather clarifying.

Comment: Nice. We agree on the required functionality.

Comment: @TomSharpe thank you so much! It works on the sample, I'll check on the main dataset today.

Answer (score 2):

### Maximum Consecutive Days of Occurrence

```
=LET(data,A2:B18,dcol,1,icol,2,
    d,INDEX(data,,dcol),
    i,INDEX(data,,icol),
    iu,SORT(UNIQUE(i)),
    ic,BYROW(iu,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        du,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(d,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(i,r))))),
        MAX(IFERROR(SCAN(1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(du)-1),LAMBDA(sr,r,
            IF(INDEX(du,r+1)-INDEX(du,r)=1,sr+1,1))),1))))),
    HSTACK(iu,ic))
```

[image]

| Date | ID number | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 | 200 | also tomorrow |
| 01/01/2024 | 300 | also tomorrow |
| 01/01/2024 | 100 | not tomorrow |
| 01/02/2024 | 300 | also yesterday |
| 01/02/2024 | 200 | also yesterday and tomorrow |
| 01/02/2024 | 300 | today's duplicate |
| 01/02/2024 | 400 | also tomorrow |
| 01/03/2024 | 400 | also yesterday |
| 01/03/2024 | 200 | also yesterday and tomorrow |
| 01/03/2024 | 200 | today's duplicate |
| 01/03/2024 | 100 | also tomorrow |
| 01/04/2024 | 200 | also yesterday and tomorrow |
| 01/04/2024 | 300 | neither yesterday nor tomorrow |
| 01/04/2024 | 100 | also yesterday |
| 01/05/2024 | 400 | not yesterday |
| 01/05/2024 | 200 | also yesterday |
| 01/05/2024 | 400 | today's duplicate |

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, then the following formula should work in accordance with the respective description in the post. That said:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _IDNumber, B2:B18,
     _DateOfDay, A2:A18,
     _MatchRelativePositions, XMATCH(_DateOfDay&"|"&_IDNumber,_DateOfDay&"|"&_IDNumber),
     _Bins, ROW(_DateOfDay)-ROW(TAKE(_DateOfDay,1))+1,
     BYROW(C2#,LAMBDA(x,AGGREGATE(14,7,FREQUENCY(_MatchRelativePositions,_Bins)/(x=_IDNumber),1))))
```

---

Alternatively, if one not using `MS365` then can use the following:

```
=AGGREGATE(
    14,
    7,
    FREQUENCY(
        XMATCH(
            $A$2:$A$18 & "|" &
                $B$2:$B$18,
            $A$2:$A$18 & "|" &
                $B$2:$B$18
        ),
        ROW($A$2:$A$18) -
            ROW($A$2) + 1
    ) / (C2 = $B$2:$B$18),
    1
)
```

---

The above usage and algorithms has been explained here as well:

**[Count the unique Values that met the Criterias (without using Pivot and Unique() function)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869179/8162520)**

Comment: Great. Both show the expected `1,2,2,2` for my sample data.